# Get transaction history with PayPal API

Tags: java, paypal

I want to get the list of all the transactions for an account. According to the API I am using the TransactionSearch API. I'm also using the [example code](https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-transaction-search-java-1.6/nvp) provided by PayPal but I am not getting the correct response. As I should according to the [API](https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_TransactionSearch#id09BKCB000TA) 
here is what i am getting in response Timestamp :

```
INFO [NVPAPICaller] - TIMESTAMP=2012%2d04%2d14T10%3a41%3a27Z&CORRELATIONID=5e18132a3167&ACK=Success&VERSION=51%2e0&BUILD=2769757 Ack : 200  Elapsed Time : 2,491 ms
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

solved using the TransactionSearch